# multiple datasources in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to using two database connections w/in a Spring Boot (v1.2.3) application as described in the docs (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources.

Problem seems to be that the secondary datasource is getting constructed with the properties for the primary datasource.

Can someone point out what I'm missing here?

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate secondaryJdbcTemplate(DataSource secondaryDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(secondaryDataSource)
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "primaryJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource primaryDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(primaryDataSource)
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run Application, args
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.primary.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@example.com:1521:DB1
spring.datasource.primary.username=user1
spring.datasource.primary.password=
spring.datasource.primary.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@example.com:1521:DB2
spring.datasource.secondary.username=user2
spring.datasource.secondary.password=
spring.datasource.secondary.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `JdbcTemplate` beans will be getting created with the primary `DataSource`. You can use `@Qualifier` to have the secondary `DataSource` injected into the secondary `JdbcTemplate`. Alternatively, you could call the `DataSource` methods directly when creating the `JdbcTemplate` beans.